# Angular 2/Typescript: filtering array does not return expected result

Tags: angular, typescript

In my filterProducts() function, I have two conditional tests. The following filters the products if products of the type passed in to the function are found and it works as expected:

```
if (filterCriteria.type) {
  filteredProducts = filteredProducts.filter(product => 
     product.producttype == filterCriteria.type);
}
```

The second test is supposed to filter the products based on the category passed in to the function:

```
if (filterCriteria.category) {

  console.log("ProductService.filterCriteria.category = " + filterCriteria.category);

  filteredProducts = filteredProducts.filter(product => 
    {
      console.log("ProductService.product.category = " + product.category);

      product.category == filterCriteria.category;

      if(product.category == filterCriteria.category) {
        console.log("ProductService.product.category = filterCriteria.category ");
      }
    });
}
```

The log statements in the code shows that, yes, there are products of the category passed into the function but at the end the filteredProducts array which is supposed to hold the products found contains no data.

The two segments are nearly identical. One works, the other doesn't.

Below is the function in its entirety:

```
  public filterProducts(filterCriteria: FilterCriteria): Product[] {
    let filteredProducts = this.products;
    let tmp = this.products;


    if (filterCriteria.category) {

      console.log("ProductService.filterCriteria.category = " + 
          filterCriteria.category);

      filteredProducts = filteredProducts.filter(product => 
        {
          console.log("ProductService.product.category = " + 
              product.category);

          product.category == filterCriteria.category;

          if(product.category == filterCriteria.category) {
            console.log("ProductService.product.category = 
                filterCriteria.category ");
          }
        });
    }

    console.log("filteredProducs 1.length = " + filteredProducts.length)

    if (filterCriteria.type) {
      filteredProducts = filteredProducts.filter(product => 
          product.producttype == filterCriteria.type);
   }

    console.log("filteredProducs.length = " + filteredProducts.length)
    return filteredProducts;
  }
```

Comment: I know the SOP is to *not* say anything if you down vote ... but as a relatively new person here I'm very interested why this is down voted. This seems like an entirely valid and complete question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code segment:

```
if (filterCriteria.type) {
  filteredProducts = filteredProducts.filter(product => 
     product.producttype == filterCriteria.type); // <- Implicit return of this value to the filter function.
}
```

There is only one line within your arrow function. So by default, it uses it as a return statement. So your code above is basically a short cut for this:

```
if (filterCriteria.type) {
  filteredProducts = filteredProducts.filter(product => 
     return (product.producttype == filterCriteria.type));
}
```

The second set of code is multiple lines, so you need an explicit return statement.

```
if (filterCriteria.category) {

  console.log("ProductService.filterCriteria.category = " + filterCriteria.category);

  filteredProducts = filteredProducts.filter(product => 
    {
      console.log("ProductService.product.category = " + product.category);

      if(product.category == filterCriteria.category) {
        console.log("ProductService.product.category = filterCriteria.category ");
      }

      return product.category == filterCriteria.category;  //<-- RETURN
    });
}
```

For example, here is one from my code. Both of these are identical in terms of functionality.

**Single line arrow function with implicit return:**

```
performFilter(filterBy: string): IProduct[] {
    filterBy = filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase();
    return this.products.filter((product: IProduct) =>
          product.productName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1);
}
```

**Multi-line arrow function with explicit return**

```
performFilter(filterBy: string): IProduct[] {
    filterBy = filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase();
    return this.products.filter((product: IProduct) => {
        console.log(product.productName);
        return product.productName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1;  // <-- Inner return returns for this ONE item within the filter function
    })
}
```

Comment: I do not wish to return after only one  segment is executed. I wish to filter based on category first then based on type and the resulting filteredproducts array is returned at the end of the function. If I were to include return statements in each segment (if I understand you correctly) only one segment of the function would execute at a time which is not the result I desire.

Comment: The return statement within a arrow function return to that function. So in this example, they return to the filter method so it can process the next one. Your other option is to simply remove all of your log statements so you are back to a single line function with a default return. :-)

Comment: Thanks, Deborah, I will try your suggestion. But I think the segment of code only contained one statement previously and it still did not produce the correct result. I only added the log statements for testing purposes. I will remove them and test it again.

Comment: If that is the case, then something else is wrong. Try commenting out the second if (filterCriter.type) to see if this filter works without the second filter.

Comment: I removed the log statements and added the return. It worked like a charm. Thank you, Deborah.